# Cannot see the output of a compiled C++ script with Qt in the terminal

Tags: c++, g++, qt-creator, clang++

Using QT Creator 4.12.14
QT 5.15
MacOS 10.14.6

I'm trying to run a simple script named `main.cpp` in the folder `hello1` in Qt

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "hello world";
  return 0;
}
```

I can compile and run the script without any problem from the terminal:

```
[mymac@hello1]$ which g++-9
/usr/local/bin/g++-9
[mymac@hello1]$ g++-9 -o main main.cpp
[mymac@hello1]$ ./main
hello world%
```

However when I compile the script in Qt Creator (which picks by defauft the compiler `Clang (C++, x86 64bit in /usr/bin)`), no executable is created and the code is not run. What happens is that a terminal window pops up with this on screen:

```
/var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/tmpMNS3x9 ; exit;
[mymac@documents]$ /var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/tmpMNS3x9 ; exit;
[mymac@documents]$
```

Moreover (if it helps), In the Qt Creator - 4 Compile tab, there is this output:

```
19:30:02: Running steps for project hello1...
19:30:02: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
19:30:02: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -j8
make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
19:30:02: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
19:30:02: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Moreover I can successfully compile the code found on [this link](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1186/qtcreator/simple-project.zip)

What am I doing wrong and cannot compile the simple `main.cpp` script? Is it because, I'm using 2 different compilers? What is the exact workaround to compile the script in QT?

The content of the `.pro` file is the following:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**EDIT**
after trying around, QT does indeed compile if you select "release" instead of "Debug" in the menu down left. The executable reside in a parent directory. The output can be seen in the console if `project > run > run in terminal` is unchecked. However, if I check that box the same of terminal (without `hello world` appears:

```
/var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/tmpMNS3x9 ; exit;
[mymac@documents]$ /var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/tmpMNS3x9 ; exit;
[mymac@documents]$
```

What should I do so that the executable runs in the terminal?

Comment: what is the content of your *pro* file ? Do you have `make: Nothing to be done for 'first'` if you modify *main.cpp* and redo ?

Comment: @bruno I edited the question and added the content of the .pro file. I also edited the question: it does successfully compile but it appears thet there is a problem for Qt to directly run the working executable in the terminal

Comment: what do you mean "*there is a problem for Qt to directly run the working executable in the terminal*" ? Your program is *not* a QT program, I mean there is no graphic / windows creation, just start it by hand in a terminal, and also also do `cout << "hello world" << endl;` to flush the output and produce a newline

Comment: I mean I would like QT to spontaneously run the compiled executable (such as seen in this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJTuknZ3mgM", instead of having to run it by searching the executable in finder and then double click on it)

Comment: you say *The output can be seen in the console if project > run > run in terminal is unchecked* so you can run it and see the result, I do not understand you

Comment: The video you give is a QT program contrarily to your case which is a 'standard' C program, this is completely different

Comment: it's a detail: the question is indeed much more serious than originaly posted: QT does compile successfully. But when running the script from inside qt (and compiling), a terminal window pops up with ```/var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/tmpMNS3x9 ; exit;
[mymac@documents]$ /var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/tmpMNS3x9 ; exit;
[mymac@documents]$ ```. and no `hello world` appears

Comment: I just retried step by step to reproduce the video (and copied the script of the video in a new project): i still get the same terminal output stated as before